# DELETE ... INTO ... FROM (SELECT)

Tags: delete, memory-optimized-tables

I am wondering why this is coded this way.

```
declare @messages table
       ([SEQUENCE_ID] BIGINT,
        [MESSAGE_ID] BIGINT
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SEQUENCE_ID]))
;
delete T
output deleted.SEQUENCE_ID,
       deleted.MESSAGE_ID
  into @messages
 from (select top (65536) *
         from source
        order by SEQUENCE_ID) T
;
```

What is the benefit of this over a simpler appearing SELECT ... INTO @messages ?
I can see one possible, that the DELETE T will free up any locks on the source table.
Another may be that SELECT INTO creates a heap, which then needs reordering on the key, so this reduces IO operations.

But what are the underlying reasons why this code is a good idea ?
I am assuming it *is* a good idea because it's in production code.

Comment: It's a DELETE ... OUTPUT.  So it deletes the source rows that it inserts into the table variable.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, David.

That was not either of the questions I asked.

1) what's the benefit of this over SELECT ... INTO


2) why is it a good idea


I can't find any _explanations_ of code like this. Lots of short examples of this construct, but no reasons **why** it would be preferable to adopt this.


It's the difference between useless documentation, and useful explanation.

Comment: It does something completely different from SELECT ... INTO.  DELETE ... OUTPUT is commonly used to treat a table as a queue.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#queues

Comment: It's a single statement, rather than selecting and deleting from two different tables, and can be more performant and less prone to deadlocks

Comment: "What is the benefit of this over" - hard to compare two things that have different effects. You could [edit your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/314063/edit) to include code you think is equivalent, _then_ comparing benefits would be a valid question.

Comment: David, Aakashm: I can understand the queue implementation if it deleted from a table.  But this is deleting from a (nested?) query result, so how does it affect the table "source" that is aliased as T ?

Comment: Charlieface: I suspect that deadlocks is the reason, this is from an application that can be multi-instanced on several clients to one DB server, so anything that releases locks quicker and minimises deadlocks is a good thing.  Plus the applicaiton is multi-threaded so this can also execute in many threads on each client.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you say

> I can understand the queue implementation if it deleted from a table.
> But this is deleting from a (nested?) query result, so how does it
> affect the table "source" that is aliased as T ?

So one specific thing you don't know about is what happens here:

```
CREATE TABLE Rabbit ( Id int, Name nvarchar(200) );

INSERT Rabbit ( Id, Name ) VALUES 
  ( 1, 'Flopsy' )
, ( 2, 'Mopsy' )
;

DELETE T FROM ( SELECT * FROM Rabbit ) T
```

to which I can only suggest *try it* !

---

What you should just have discovered is that this deletes records *from the underlying table*. Now, this (obviously) wouldn't work for *every* subquery, but it works for this one.

So, we can use this construct in exactly the 'use a table as a queue' mechanism that you already understand.

Why the subquery rather than just `DELETE TOP ( 65536 )`? Because that wouldn't allow us to say *which* 65536 records we most wanted deleted - you can't put an `ORDER BY` in a `DELETE`.